# gitlab-runner docker: command not found

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build docker container using GitLab runner.
(lead dev left company, and now I have no idea how to do it.)

I'll share everything I can.

Build output
[image: output error]

as I understand from output runner is assigned correctly, the problem is with docker

***the runner is running as Shell executor***

here is **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  STACK_NAME: isnta_api
  VERSION: ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
  IMAGE_NAME: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}

before_script:
  - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
  - echo $STACK_NAME
  - echo $CI_REGISTRY
  - echo $IMAGE_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${IMAGE_NAME}  .
    - docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-compose.yml ${STACK_NAME}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: ${STACK_NAME}
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    environment:
      PORT: 4042
      APP_ENV: production
      INSTAGRAM_API_KEY: de194cf559msh8d940d38fd1ca47p129005jsnc11b4fd77a36
      INSTAGRAM_API_HOST_NAME: instagram-bulk-profile-scrapper.p.rapidapi.com
      INSTAGRAM_API_BASE_URL: https://instagram-bulk-profile-scrapper.p.rapidapi.com/clients/api/ig/
    networks:
      - nxnet
    ports:
      - 4042:4042
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: start-first

networks:
  nxnet:
    external: true
```

and **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD npm run start:prod
```

Any suggestions or tips would be valuable. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for sure if Docker is installed on the machine/VM that has the runner on it?  Depending on your setup, you can SSH into the machines that host the Gitlab runners and just do `docker --version`.

If it's not on there, then you will need to visit https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ and add it.

I ran into the same situation, coming into a project that used GitLab runners with no prior experience - at the end of the day, a GitLab runner is just a program that can run on any machine.  Depending on how your CI/CD is configured, it may be on a development VM, server, workstation, etc.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your .gitlab-ci.yml and Dockerfile are fine, the problem is on the Gitlab Runner that executes the CI pipeline.

The runner cannot access its Docker Engine, either because it is not installed  on the runner or the runner is not configured to run in `privileged` mode, which is necessary to use Docker in your CI.

1. Check if Docker is installed
   If you have access to the machine which hosts the runner, check if Docker is installed there
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/
2. Active privileged mode in the Gitlab Runner Configuration

in config.toml:

`privileged = true`

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

Also check the Gitlab CI Documentation on how to use Docker here
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html